# The function with different parameters in C++ Inheritance and Polymorphism

Tags: c++, inheritance

Recently, I am learning Inheritance and Polymorphism in C++.

I made three classes: Node, uni_dir_Node(uni-direction Node), and bi_dir_Node(bi-direction Node).

Here is my code:

```
class Node {
   protected:
       string name;
       Node* next;
       virtual void connect(Node* _Node) = 0;
};

class uni_dir_Node : public Node {
    void connect(Node* _Node) {
        this->next = next;
    }
};

class bi_dir_Node : public Node {
    Node* previous;

    void connect(Node* next_Node, Node* previous_Node) {
        this->next = next;
        this->previous = previous_Node;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node* head = new bi_dir_Node;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course there is a compiler error in this code.

My question is, the function `connect()` in class uni_dir_Node has one parameter but for the function `connect()` in class bi_dir_Node has two parameters. How do I keep this inheritance structure and make it legal?

Is there any good way to solve this problem?

Comment: the functions needs to have the same signature.

Comment: A `Node` is constructable with a `Node *`. A `bi_dir_Node` is not. Therefore a `bi_dir_Node` cannot be a `Node`. You can add a constructor for `bi_dir_Node` that takes a single `Node *` and sets the other `Node * ` to `nullptr` or makes `previous = next = node`, but that is just asking for trouble. Your problem is just not suitable for inheritance and you shouldn't force it.

Comment: @nwp It's not a constructor, but a pure virtual function. Otherwise the argument is right: either provide an implementation of `connect()` with only one argument, or fully reschedule the inheritance.

Comment: I see... Thanks for ur suggestion. It makes me understand the Inheritance more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, the problem is that `bi_dir_Node` doesn't have a `void connect(Node* _Node)` method.

Conceptually, what's going on is that inheritance indicates an "is a" relationship. Saying that `bi_dir_Node` inherits from `Node` means that `bi_dir_Node` *is a* `Node`, so anything that a `Node` can do, a `bi_dir_Node` can do.

You're trying to say that `bi_dir_Node` is a `Node` but that it can't do everything a `Node` can: specifically, it can't `Connect` with a single argument.

The solution is to either provide a single-argument `Connect` for `bi_dir_Node` or to remove or redesign the inheritance structure. For example, in C++, templates may be a better approach: you can make `uni_dir_Node` and `bi_dir_Node` completely separate (not part of the same inheritance hierarchy) and write template classes and template functions that are generic enough to operate on both.

Answer (score 0):

As says nwp, to have polymorphism, you need to have functions with the same prototypes in the derived classes.

By prototype, it means :

1. same return type
2. Same parameter list
3. const keyword at the end of the prototype must be present on derived if present on base method
4. same method name of course

This is because all functions need to be called the same way and same semantic whether it is a base or derived object.

`virtual` key word must be put on the base class method prototype.
The `virtual` behavior is inherited. So it can be put or not on derived class overriden methods.

Advanced stuff - not often useful :

Since C++ 98 (prehistory !), if a base class method is

```
Base * Method();
```

The derived method can be :

```
Derived * Method();
```

This is because Derived* IS A KIND of Base*

Hope it clarifies